# Forcing onNext() upon button click

Tags: rx-java

The following code emits items from a list using `Observable.from()`. With each item, a `flatMap()` with a maxConcurrent value of 1 is performed with the `Observable` from `devide.connectForPolice()`. The `device.connectForPolice()` method performs a number of operations on the current item, and will eventually call `Observable.just()` to move on to the next item. Here is the code:

```java
mConnectingSubscription = Observable.from(mAdapter.getItems())
                .flatMap(device -> {
                    return device.connectForPolice(device.getName());
                }, 1)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        if (s.contains("str")) {
                            mAdapter.removeItem(s);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I will be adding a button to the screen when this code starts to run, and upon click I would like to "force" the current item from the original `Observable.from(mAdapter.getItems())` to complete so the next item in the list can go through the chain. It is essentially a "skip" or "finish" button. What is the best way to integrate that into this chain of events?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the exact behavior you want to achieve. If it is sufficient enough to just ignore the result of `device.connectForPolice(device.getName())` then the solution is trivial. Just merge this stream with another that represents clicks on this skip button and take only 1 item, whichever comes first.

```
.flatMap(device -> {
    return device.connectForPolice(device.getName())
               .mergeWith(RxView.clicks(skipBtn).map(voidObject -> someString))
               .take(1);
}, 1)
```

However, I assume that there are heavy computations involved so I think you want to interrupt them when the user decides to skip. In that case, I think you'll have to write your own producer and listen for clicks in there to stop computation immediately.